# Strings - Filling In Leading Zeros Wtih A Zero

Tags: java, string

I'm reading an array of hard-coded strings of numeric characters - all positions are filled with a character, even for the leading zeros. Thus, can confidently parse it using substring(start, end) to convert to numeric.

Example: "0123 0456 0789"

However, a string coming from a database does not fill in the leading zero with a 'zero character', it simply fetches the '123 456 789', which is correct for an arithmetic number but not for my needs and makes for parsing trouble.

Before writing conditionals to check for leading zeros and adding them to the string if needed, is there a simple way of specifying they be filled with a character ?  I'm not finding this in my Java book...

I could have done the three conditionals in the time it took to post this but, this is more about 'education'...

Thanks

Comment: So you want to know if there's an easier way than doing it with three conditionals?  And will all of them be in 4 number chunks?

Comment: If you are passing the strings to numeric, why would the leading zero be a problem? Do you need to use the substring?

Answer (score 2):

An easier way to do it would be to use `string.split()` to separate the numbers, instead of pulling out specific character indices.

Comment: Thanks, all. Hopefully commenting here will address the other comments... I could have been clearer: The DB saves a float to a string and strips off leading zeros. Upon reading the DB, I get the string sans leading zeros.  I need the leading zeros so I can use the parse code (used elsewhere in the app). So, it seems I can test for indexed char and fill in "0" or, do something else, as suggested. Splitting still leaves me with needing to fill in "0" so, I'm liking the "%010d" idea. I'm not clear on DB.replaceAll (seems I'd need to write that method).

Comment: @headscratch: If your parsing code *needs* the leading zeroes, then your parsing code is too brittle. You should rewrite the parsing code instead of trying to fix the problem elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

String.format("%010d", number);
or
fromDB.replaceAll(" ", "0");
or possibly even better, fix it in the DB.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps `StringUtils` from `org.apache.commons.lang` could be useful for you:

```
StringUtils.leftPad("123", 4, '0') = "0123"
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple regex way:

```
String input = "123 456 789";
String output = input.replaceAll("\\b[1-9]\\d*", "0$0");
System.out.println(output); //prints "0123 0456 0789"
```

This replaces all "words" consisting of any digit but beginning with 1-9 (not 0) with the same word, prefixed by 0.

I agree with the other assessments that you should just make your parsing less fragile, using something like `String.split()` instead of requiring fixed widths.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another method is to use DecimalFormat:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("####")'

String fourDigitString = df.format(numberFromDB);
```

Comment: Thanks - I'm using that approach for several float numbers in the code but I didn't consider it for this string after parsing - this may be the best solution for me (been trying the others and they all have merits but still require some massaging).